# Strip Pod as Pod from Perl file

Tags: perl

I am trying to extract the Pod documentation from a Perl file. I do not want to convert the documentation to text as is done by [`Pod::Simple::Text`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod::Simple::Text). I just want the Pod text as Pod text, such that I can feed it into [`Pod::Template`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod::Template) later. For example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Pod::Simple::Text;
my $ps=Pod::Simple::Text->new();
my $str;
$ps->output_string( \$str );
$ps->parse_file($0);
print $str;

__END__

=head1 SYNOPSIS

prog [OPTIONS]
```

This will print the Pod as text. Is there a CPAN module that can give me the Pod text, that is:

```
=head1 SYNOPSIS

prog [OPTIONS]
```

instead?

**Update**

The solution should be able to handle Pod docs in strings, like

```
my $str = '__END__

=head1 SYNOPSIS';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using [`PPI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use PPI;

# Slurp source code
my $src = do { local ( @ARGV, $/ ) = $0; <> };

# Load a document
my $doc = PPI::Document->new( \$src );

# Find all the pod within the doc
my $pod = $doc->find('PPI::Token::Pod');
for (@$pod) {
    print $_->content, "\n";
}

=comment
Hi Pod
=cut

1;

__END__

=head1 SYNOPSIS

prog [OPTIONS]
```

Outputs:

```
=comment
Hi Pod
=cut

=head1 SYNOPSIS

prog [OPTIONS]
```

Comment: Thanks for this great solution. It even works with Pod docs embedded in strings, like `my $str='__END__

=head1 SYNOPSIS';`

Answer (score 4):

Use the `-u` option for [`perldoc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldoc.html). This strips out the POD and displays it raw.

If you want to extract the POD from within a Perl program, you could do something like this:

```
my $rawpod;
if (open my $fh, '-|', 'perldoc', '-u', $filename) {
  local $/;
  my $output = <$fh>;
  if (close $fh) {
    $rawpod = $output;
  }
}
```

If you *really* don't want to run `perldoc` as an executable, you might be interested that the `perldoc` executable is a very simple wrapper around `Pod::Perldoc` which you might want to consider using yourself.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work with Pod docs embedded in strings. See my updated question for an example..

Comment: Well, if you change the question, it's not that surprising that a given answer no longer works. I'm pleased you've found a solution to your new question.

Comment: The problem with `perldoc` is that there is a bug, so it thinks Pod embedded in a string belongs to the document.

Answer (score 1):

Pod::Simple::SimpleTree will give it to you as a parse tree. You can convert that back to POD source easily enough.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply grepping the pods from the file:

```
open SR, $0;
print grep /^=/../^=cut$/, <SR>;
close SR;
```